# Defining variable within if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

I want to assign a value to a variable when a condition is verified like this

```
if (k<12){

var Case=4;

}
```

The problem when i call this variable to be printed in the body of the page i get undefined

```
document.write(Case);
```

Comment: @NenadVracar it's true

Comment: It should work then https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1902/

Comment: @NenadVracar its `false` statement .Because `k` is undefined .And `case` also defined inside the if is true .So you get undefined .declare the `case` as a global one.And don't forget define the `k`

Comment: @NenadVracar i have big code and the var declaration is in a function in the head and the call is in the body

Comment: what *default* value should `Case` have in advance?

Comment: You need to provide a real [mcve]. With this code, it won't give you undefined. It will give you a reference error because `k` isn't declared.

Comment: If the variable is declared in a function that is different because in js functions have its own scope and you can access that variable only in that function https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1904/

Answer (score 3):

Basically your [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) gets hoisted and assigned with `undefined`.

> Variable declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any code is executed. The scope of a variable declared with `var` is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global. If you re-declare a JavaScript variable, it will not lose its value.

Order of execution:

```
var Case;        // hoisted, value: undefined

if (k < 12) {
    Case = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting undefined because you have not actually defined it. You are defining it when the condition is true. You should write the code like this.

```
var Case = null;
var k = 0;

if(k > 14) {
  Case = 3;
}

document.write(Case);
```

I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Case = 0;
if(k<12){
  Case = 4;
}
document.write(Case);
```

You need to define it first so if k<12 == False it wont be undefined.